# Format String become xxx1, xx10 or 1###, 10## etc

Tags: java, string, formatting

I have following numbers : 1, 2, 3, 4, 10

But I want to print those numbers like this:

```
0001
0002
0003
0004
0010
```

I have searched in Google. the keyword is number format. But I've got nothing, I just get, format decimal such ass `1,000,000.00`. I hope you can suggest me a reference or give me something to solve this problem.

Thanks

Edit,
we can use NumberFormat, or String.format("%4d", somevalue); but it just for adding `0` character before integer. How If I wanna use character such as `x`, `#` or maybe `whitespace`. 
So the character become:
`xxxx1`
`xxx10`  or `####1` `###10` or `1####`  `10###`

Comment: @Martijn Courteaux: If you think this question is a duplicate (and I'd be very surprised if it weren't), say so in a comment and we can vote to close this one.  The "deja-vu" tag was cute, but it's not how we do things around here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("0000");
System.out.println(nf.format(10));
```

This prints "0010".

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [this](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

What you want to do is "Pad" your result.
e.g. `String.format("%04d", myValue)`;

Answer (score 4):

You can use `String.format();`

```
public static String addLeadingZeroes(int size, int value)
{
    return String.format("%0"+size+"d", value);
}
```

So in your situation:

```
System.out.println(addLeadingZeroes(4, 75));
```

prints

```
0075
```

Comment: I think it would read more natural: `"...Zeroes( int zeros, int value ) "` to be used like: `addLeadingZeroes( 4, 75 )`

Comment: @Oscar: I don't think so. Because you can pass `4` for size and `75` for value. Then you will have only two zeroes and not four.

Comment: Maybe, but reading `addLeadingZeroes( 75, 4 )` gives me the impression there would be 74 zeros in front of the number 4. :-/ Mangst answer makes sense  :)

Comment: @Oscar: Oh, that is what you mean. Better?

Answer (score 0):

For a perverse answer.

```
int i = 10;
System.out.println((50000 + i + "").substring(1));
```

prints

```
0010
```